# Nginx how to serve digest favicon file when request is for non-digest favicon.ico

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm using Nginx in front of a rails app. Nginx is serving static assets from public with the following location rule:

```
location ~ ^/assets/ {
            gzip_static     on;
            gzip            off;
            expires         1y;
            add_header      Cache-Control public;
            add_header      Last-Modified "";
            add_header      ETag "";
            break;
        }
```

This is working fine for the standard Rails digest assets but every now and then I get a request for `/favicon.ico` directly which will fail as it is a non-digest asset.

What I'd like to do is use a Nginx location directive to map/alias/rewrite `/favicon.ico` to `/assets/favicons/favicon-somereallylongdigest.ico`.

As rails will keep up to the last 3 assets there could be three files which match, I'm not worried about that and are happy to match any of the files found.

I'm not strong on Nginx config so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a permanent redirect:

```
location = /favicon.ico {
    return 301 $scheme://$host/assets/favicons/favicon-somereallylongdigest.ico;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the value of somereallylongdigest up front. It could be anything, I need a rule that can match the files without knowing the value eg, just match the word favicon- or something.

Comment: I see. What about creating/updating a symlink, e.g. `ln -s assets/favicons/favicon-*.ico favicon.ico`?

Comment: That is awesome! The symlink worked. Even better because this is all happening in a docker container it is auto-refreshed on build any time the digest icon is changed.